# What to include in php page to use wordpress's functions?

Tags: php, include, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I want to create a page that also has javascript and upon a certain user action the javascript calls the server with an AJAX request.
This is a GET request to a php script I created. Since I extended wordpress with my plugin I put this php in my plugin's folder.

The problem is that from this php script I want to access everything that wordpress offers, e.g. the database access, but I do not know how.

What do I have to include in this php file in order to access the functions offered by wordpress? I wanted to use database access so I included the wp-db.php file and declared the global wpdb variable, but it did not help.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has it's own build in ajax: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
Use this instead of your own ajax script.

In this ajax script you can use all WP functions. It will also make your plugin more like wordpress standards.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in he [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) itself.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

By using the blog header no database queries are executed by default, you have to supply the `get_posts` that will fetch what-ever articles you need based on your application's parameters:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title'); ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>    
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to go, just use the build in ajax api, it will be better for preformance. codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: I think the question was less detailed when i answered. (I might be wrong) but when i answered the question only asked how to include a WordPress bootstrap.

Comment: The question stayed the same, I did not modify it. Although it is true that I should have named it more in a way that reflects the content of the topic. Sorry about that.